# When are the parameters used in WebResource.axd reset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webresource.axd

When using WebResource.axd you will see two parameters being passed in the query string.  Usually looks something like this:

```
WebResource.axd?d=9H3mkymBtDwEocEoKm-S4A2&t=634093400273197793
```

I have run into an issue where I need a permanent link to the resource in question.  Recently the link I was using stopped working.  What would cause these ids to change?  Rebooting the server? Recompiling the code?  Is there anyway to make these ids permanent?

Background -

As part of a site monitoring service we are subscribed to, we have "recorded" several sets of user actions for our website.  For example, we recorded the process of logging into the site.  The monitoring is now saying that the user login process fails (it's working fine) because it cannot find the WebResource.axd with the ids it recorded.

Comment: I think `t=634093400273197793` is a timestamp, so it will change every so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page provides all the information on the makeup of the URL

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442

> The "d" stands for the requested Web Resource

Something worth noting is that you don't need to have the timestamp (t) parameter there to call the resource. Try it on your own site, view the source and grab a webresource.axd url and navigate to the it, remove the `t`

Comment: (t) indicates the time period for which the resource is valid

Comment: Not according to MSDN "The "t" is the timestamp for the requested assembly, which can help in determining if there have been any changes to the resource."

Comment: @Darren _The "d" stands for the requested Web Resource_... or more specifically, _d_ stands for _digest_.

Comment: I know this is a very old post but the link included in the response is no longer available.